# Swift 5.0 Best way to assign value to an array object which stored in EnvironmentObject

Tags: xcode, xcode11, swift5

I have a struct model called Questions stored in a ObservableObject class with @Published Method

```
struct Question: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var questionText: String
    var questionComment: String

}

class DataRep: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var showFavoritesOnly = false
    @Published var QuestionList : [Question] = QuestionListData
    @Published var selectedCategory = "all"
}
```

Later in the List View I am reading questions and adding to a list, in the navigation, I am passing the question to the new view which is stored in @State

```
struct QuestionCommentView: View {
    @State var question : Question
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination:QuestionCommentEntryView(question: question))
        {
            Text(question.questionText)
            Text(question.questionComment)
       }
    }
}
```

In the QuestionCommentEntryView, I have a text field, where I read a "comment data" with button click and wish to store it with the array in the EnvironmentObject so the other views can reach to the updated comment.

```
import SwiftUI

struct QuestionCommentEntryViewTest: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var datarep: DataRep  //forced to declare
    @State var question : Question
    @State private var enteredComment = ""

    //Binding
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Comment", text: $enteredQuestionComment)
            Button (action: {
                self.AddScaleComment ()
            })
            {Text("Add Comment")}

        }
    }

    func AddScaleComment ()
    {
        let questions : [Question] = datarep.QuestionList
        ForEach (questions) {q in
            if q.id = question.id
            {
                let quest.questionComment = self.enteredComment
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question 1: Is there a easier way of implementing such logic

Question 2: How can I ensure the update on the QuestionCommentView refresh as I want to show the updated comment.

Question 3: Why ForEach is giving the following errors. I used the same syntax I used in other pages of my app. Errors are:
(a) Use of undeclared type 'Question'
(b) Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Regards,

M

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@State` (which should be used only as private internal view state), pass your `question` as `@Binding` (callers, as not provided in your snapshot, should be needed to modify correspondingly).

Schematically it should be like...

```
struct QuestionCommentView: View {
    @Binding var question : Question
    ...

    NavigationLink(destination:QuestionCommentEntryView(question: $question))
```

and

```
struct QuestionCommentEntryViewTest: View {
    @Binding var question : Question
    ...
```

Thus you'll be able to modify exactly original `question` in

```
func AddScaleComment ()
{
    self.question.questionComment = self.enteredComment
}
```

so, as it is binding to value in original array, it will be updated as well.